# CardView me está recordando el ImageButton

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un formulario en XML que contiene un CardView para darle forma redonda a un ImageView, estoy intentando colocar un ImageButton que se coloque por encima de este ImageView que tendrá como finalidad añadir una imagen desde la galería, pero la funcionalidad es lo de menos, el caso es que el ImageButton se esta recortando también y no aparece completo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rlAnimated"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundappet">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Vamos a añadir una mascota"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlImageDefault"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:elevation="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="80dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/et_rounded_add_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_image" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPetImageForm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"></ImageView>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlImageDefault"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp">


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spTypePets"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
                android:dropDownWidth="300dp"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                app:backgroundTint="#FF8D00" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPetName"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spTypePets"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#FF8D00"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Nombre de la mascota"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="19dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="#FC6600"
        android:text="Añadir"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Llevo ya un rato dándole vueltas pero no se donde ponerlo para que esté en esa posición y que no lo recorte, a ver si me podéis echar una mano, o al final tendré que tirarme de los pelos y nadie quiere eso...

Answer (score 0):

Me vuelvo a responder a mi mismo. He usado Glide para redondear la imagen directamente:

```
Glide.with(PetsFormActivity.this).load(R.drawable.dog).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(ivPetImageForm);
```

Me he deshecho del CardView y ya he podido colocar el ImageButton bien, dejo el trozo de código:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlImageDefault"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPetImageForm"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_rounded_add_image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_image" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```